# Recursively convert ES6 to ES5 using babel with grunt

Tags: gruntjs, babeljs

My grunt file is as follows :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
clean: {
  js: ['src/*.min.js']
},
babel: {
   files: {
       expand: true,
       src: ['src/*.js','src/*/*.js','src/*/*/*.js'],
       ext: '-modified.js'
   },
   options: {
       sourceMap: false,
       presets: ['babel-preset-es2015']
   }
},
 watch: {
  tasks: ['babel']
}

});
grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean','babel']);
};
```

Is there a better way to configure "src" this so that it would recursively find out the js file within src folder and subfolders and transpile those file:

```
 src: ['src/*.js','src/*/*.js','src/*/*/*.js']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those three globbing patterns:

> `src: ['src/*.js','src/*/*.js','src/*/*/*.js']`

...can be replaced with one:

```js
src: ['src/**/*.js']
```

See the text that reads:

> All most people need to know is that `foo/*.js` will match all files ending with `.js` in the `foo/` subdirectory, but `foo/**/*.js` will match all files ending with `.js` in the `foo/` subdirectory and all of its subdirectories.

... in the [Globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) of the grunt documentation.